# Unable to use 'id' selector within if condition - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to target an element with an id, whenever there is a click event. It's a pretty simple solution, no idea why this isn't working out. Please help me with it.

```js
    $('ul.main-menu li').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).siblings('li').find('a').has('#has-sub-menu')) {
            alert('sub-menu')
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="main-menu-item">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="main-menu-item">
        <a id="has-sub-menu" href="#">Company</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Working fine in code snippet. If it is not working then the only problem could be the script might be loading earlier than the HTML.

Comment: @Mr_Green wrong, click the main "home" link. it obviously does not work

Comment: oh looks like our "not working" understanding is completely different. Only OP can clarify this. To OP: Be more clear than just saying "not working".

Comment: @Mr_Green You should probably read the whole question, frame it in your mind and then make a meaning out of it in a whole. Its very much clear when I am stating `if` condition, to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the li is not the click event, the A is.

I've also made it a class of submenu. not an ID.

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="main-menu-item">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="main-menu-item">
        <a class="has-sub-menu" href="#">Company</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<script >
    $('ul.main-menu li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).hasClass('has-sub-menu')) {
            alert('sub-menu')
        }

    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add the click event on the `a` with the `id`:

```js
    $('#has-sub-menu').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            alert('sub-menu');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="main-menu-item">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="main-menu-item">
        <a id="has-sub-menu" href="#">Company</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```